# Is there a workaround for bug in Mobile Safari: Pinch to Zoom results in random scrolling blockage?

Tags: ios, css, scroll, mobile-safari, pinchzoom

I have an **image in a scrolling div**:

```
<div style="
    width:600px;height:400px;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
    top:0;left:0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">

    <img src=image.jpg width=2000 height=2000>
</div>
```

It works everywhere as expected, except that **on iOS** (8.1.3), when **I zoom in using my fingers, the DIV stops scrolling correctly**.

One can still scroll to a certain point, but i**t is impossible to view the entire image** except when it's barely zoomed at all.

I have tried hundreds of combinations of **fixed, absolute & relative positioning** on the body, the div and the image, and also **various combinations of overflow:fixed etc.** None of it works.

If I remove "**-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**", the problem goes away but scrolling loses momentum and becomes painful.

The scrolling behavior seems pretty random. Sometimes you can scroll up, sometimes not. **The problem seems to come from a conflict between the viewport scrolling and the image scrolling.**

I posted a simple example at [tech.ozake.com](http://tech.ozake.com/ipad-zoom-scroll.htm).

**Is there any way to make the image smoothly scrollable when one zooms in on it?**

*[update 23 may 2017]* This may be fixed in the next version of Mobile Safari: [news.ycombinator.com](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14384938).

Comment: This question is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968453/ios-8-safari-cant-scroll-elements-content-when-page-is-zoomed

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387666/issue-scrolling-div-with-safari-on-iphone-6-ipad-3-when-zoomed-in

Comment: 1. I've tried removing -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch - now it doesn't scroll at all...
2. FYI - I calculate the zoom level like this: window.screen.width /  window.innerWidth - the scroll functionality breaks when zoom > 1.5

Comment: I think it's a bug. If not, they may have implemented it to keep the scrolling smooth (don't have to calculate a giant image to scroll).

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer two years later. I think it's just a bug in Safari. When you pinch to zoom in iOS a virtual viewport is created that is smaller than the actual window. A scrolling event moves the smaller virtual viewport around on the overall page, and it is no longer possible to scroll a separate element on the page. It's as though the contents of the page is frozen when you pinch to zoom. One thing to try is to make the image a background image behind a text field. Presumably iOS permits scrolling a textarea box (for example) when zoomed.