# When zoomed in iOS, scrolling an overflowed div scrolls the whole page instead

Tags: ios, css, scroll, safari, zooming

Using an iPhone iOS10 in Safari, I can scroll the page and overflowed elements fine at 100% zoom.

When I zoom in, I can no longer scroll overflowed elements. The page is scrolled instead.

It appears that this issue occurs more frequently the further I've zoomed in. If I only zoom a bit, it happens less frequently.

I am using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; Removing that property will cause undesired jumping on scroll.

I've tried adjusting the element's height to 100vh vs auto vs window.innerHeight, adjusted the z-index, set it to position:absolute;

Nothing is working! Again, this only happens on zoom. Scrolling works fine at 100%.

I've seen previous threads on this issue but no solutions so far:

[iOS 8 Safari - Can't scroll element's content when page is zoomed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968453/ios-8-safari-cant-scroll-elements-content-when-page-is-zoomed)

[Is there a workaround for bug in Mobile Safari: Pinch to Zoom results in random scrolling blockage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409509/is-there-a-workaround-for-bug-in-mobile-safari-pinch-to-zoom-results-in-random)

[Issue scrolling div with Safari on iPhone 6+, iPad 3 when zoomed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387666/issue-scrolling-div-with-safari-on-iphone-6-ipad-3-when-zoomed-in)